# QGIS DB Manager hanging on import

Tags: qgis

I have a data set which is an extract from OSM. I'm only using the roads shapefile and adding labels. The extract is the state of Pennsylvania. I then tried to import this layer to PostGIS from the DB manager within QGIS. I noticed the program was unresponsive so I figured it was working on the import and I left it alone all night to do its thing. The next morning QGIS and DB manager was still unresponsive so I forced the program to quit.

I then deleted parts of the dataset I did not need in attempt to make it smaller and easier to upload and import. Tried to import VIA DB manager again, added a primary key of my choosing, specified the SRID's and clicked ok. Once again DB manager and QGIS go unresponsive.

Is this normal for QGIS when working with OSM extracts? I understand the extracts can be rather large. Should I just let DB manager do its thing and hope it finishes soon?

Comment: Which version do you use, QGIS and PostGIS? Did you try shp2pgsql? How large data set do you have?